# More than one Tunnel to 443 calls triggered

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler, http-tunneling

I am monitoring my network calls using Fiddler. When I tried opening google chrome, four "Tunnel to www.google.com:443" calls triggered. Please, I want to know, why there is more than one network call for http connect. Also, is it required that we have a http connect tunnel to :443 request for every action I perform on a particular application over the network.

Answer (score 0):

When HTTPS traffic is sent through a proxy like Fiddler, the client sends a `CONNECT` request to the proxy to tell it where to establish a connection (because of the encryption, a proxy wouldn't be able to tell otherwise).

As to why there are four connections instead of one-- All web browsers open multiple simultaneous HTTP(S) connections for performance reasons.